# redirecting url not working in localhost - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a written a service to check whether the user is already logged in or not, but here i am not able to run the code in localhost. Why i am not able to run the below code in localhost.

The redirect is not working, to redirect to the home url it should be 
res.redirect("/") isn't ?

```
function checkUser(req,res){
  // checking cookie exists
  let authenticatedUser = checkCookieExist(req.headers.cookie, "username");
  if(authenticatedUser){
    res.status(200).redirect("/home")
  }else{
    // redirect to login page, once its success redirect it to root url
    res.status(200).redirect("/")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You set invalid [response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection). In order for the redirect to work, it has to be one of the `3XX`. Usually `302` for a temporary redirect, eg.:

```
res.status(302).redirect("/")
```

This is done by default, so simple would do:

```
res.redirect("/")
```

Comment: its giving me a 404 error, but when i add the "/home" in url of browser its working but res.status(302).redirect("/home") not working giving 404 error found

Comment: any idea on this  , why its not working in the localhost